# Windows Phone 8.1 SmartCard app with background task crashing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nfc, smartcard, background-task

I got a problem I am trying to solve for over a week now and I just cannot solve it.
I am trying to make a very simple Windows Phone 8.1 app with nfc and smartcard stuff.
Later I attempt to use the smartcard emulation, provided by the Class SmartCardEmulator, but for now I just want to have a background task that does stuff when an nfc tag / smartcard is approached.
For this question I made a complete new project which contains just the basics.
The program keeps crashing when I press the button.

At start I made a **blank Windows Phone App Project** and a **Windows Runtime Component** which I added to the solution. The Phone App Project has a reference to the Windows Runtime Component Project.

In the **MainPage.xaml** I put just a **button and a textbox.**

The class BackgroundTaskManager is in the windows phone app project and the class TaskOne is in the runtime component project.

In the file Package.appxmanifest I added the background task in the declarations with **BackgroundTasks.TaskOne as EntryPoint** and **System Events as support task types**

In the **Requirements I enabled NFC**

The **Errors** I get when pressing the button are the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in SimpleNfcApp.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I tried **debugging** and put the break poin at the start of the RegisterBackgroundTask method in BackgroundTaskManager.cs and it then crashes at the end of doSomething in MainPage.xaml.cs

Here are the sourecodes:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace SimpleNfcApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
        }

        // method put on a button
        private async void doSomething(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String taskName = BackgroundTaskManager.TaskOneName;
            bool isActive = isTaskActive(taskName);

            if(isActive == false) {
                startTask();
            } else {
                myTextBox.Text = "Task already active";
            }
        }

        // starts a task
        private async void startTask()
        {
            var trigger = new SmartCardTrigger(SmartCardTriggerType.EmulatorNearFieldEntry);
            var task = BackgroundTaskManager.RegisterBackgroundTask(BackgroundTaskManager.TaskOneEntryPoint,
                                                                    BackgroundTaskManager.TaskOneName,
                                                                    trigger,
                                                                    null);
            await task;
            myTextBox.Text += task.Result.ToString();
        }

        // checks if the task is already active
        private static bool isTaskActive(String name)
        {
            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (task.Value.Name == name)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**BackgroundTaskManager.cs**

```
namespace SimpleNfcApp
{
    class BackgroundTaskManager
    {
        public const string TaskOneEntryPoint = "BackgroundTasks.TaskOne";
        public const string TaskOneName = "TaskOne";
        public static string TaskOneProgress = "";
        public static bool TaskOneRegistered = false;

        // creates and registers the task
        public static async Task<BackgroundTaskRegistration> RegisterBackgroundTask(String taskEntryPoint, String taskName, IBackgroundTrigger taskTrigger, IBackgroundCondition taskCondition)
        {
            if (TaskRequiresBackgroundAccess(taskName))
                await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = taskName;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
            builder.SetTrigger(taskTrigger);

            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

            var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            settings.Values.Remove(taskName);

            return task;
        }

        // checks if it is a windows phone app or a simple windows app
        public static bool TaskRequiresBackgroundAccess(String name)
        {
            #if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                return true;
            #else

            #endif
        }

    }
}
```

**TaskOne.cs**

```
namespace BackgroundTasks
{
    public sealed class TaskOne
    {
        IBackgroundTaskInstance _taskInstance;
        BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _taskInstance = taskInstance;
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            int x;
            x = 2 + 2;

            _deferral.Complete();
        }


    }
}
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for reading.
greez, Skippy

**EDIT:**

I added a **try catch block** around the doSomething method in MainPage.xaml.cs and got a new more telling error message.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register()
   at SimpleNfcApp.BackgroundTaskManager.<RegisterBackgroundTask>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SimpleNfcApp.MainPage.<startTask>d__0.MoveNext() Second exception caught.
```

Also, when I change the trigger in doSomething before registering the task, it works. I tried this one:

```
//var trigger = new SmartCardTrigger(SmartCardTriggerType.EmulatorNearFieldEntry);
var trigger = new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.ServicingComplete, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

U got error code there

```
var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
settings.Values.Remove(taskName);
```

ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings - to this file access denied.